# How may I Parse more than one input[type="file"] using npm's express-formidable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I want to parse not one but two input[type='file'] using express-formidable
hers what I have so far..

the HTML:

```
<form action="/edit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <b>Profile song:</b>
    <br>
    <input name"song" type="file">
```

note the `name="song"`

**Typo:** `name"song"`
problem solved smh

```
    <b>Profile picture:</b>
    <br>
    <input name="pic" type="file">
    <b>Display name:</b>
    <br>
    <input name="displayName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Display name" value="<%= currentUser.displayName || '' %>">
    <b>Bio:</b>
    <br>
    <textarea name="bio" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Tell us about yourself"><%= currentUser.bio %></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Update">
</form>
```

in `routes.js`:

```
router.post("/edit", ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body)
```

/*

```
 req.body.song is undefined

             however...

 req.body.pic IS defined
```

*/

I can't seem to find any docs which cover this topic in this context.

**So I ask:** Why am I only able to **parse** `input[name="pic"]` and not `input[name="song"]` ?

thanks in advance stackoverflowers!

```
    var file = req.body.pic
    var file_name = file.name
    var pic_type = file.type
    var pic_size = file.size
    var pic_tmp_name = pic.path.substring(pic.path.lastIndexOf("upload_"))

    req.user.profilePic = {
        path: "/uploads/"+pic_tmp_name
    }

    var song = req.body.song
    var song_name = song.name
    var song_type = song.type
    var song_size = song.size
    var song_tmp_name = song.path.substring(song.path.lastIndexOf("upload_"))

    req.user.profileSong = {
        path: "/uploads/"+song_tmp_name
    }
    req.user.displayName = req.body.displayName
    req.user.bio = req.body.bio
    req.user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        req.flash("info", "Profile Updated!")
        res.redirect("/edit")
    })
})
```

in `app.js`

```
app.use(formidable.parse({
    encoding: "utf-8",
    multiples: true,
    keepExtensions: true,
    maxFieldsSize: 1000 * 1024 * 1024, // 10mb
    maxFields: 1000,
    uploadDir: path.resolve(__dirname+"/uploads")
}))
```

Comment: You are missing the `=` in the input. Should be `<input name="song" type="file">`

Comment: yes! yes indeed. noob moves man..

Comment: May I suggest using Dev Tools in the future to inspect the element you have a problem with?

Comment: haha. I'll keep that in mind next time.